# Gen. 2:16 -17 infers "free-will" in essence, is of "binary choice" -to obey God or not to. Do we still posses "it" or not?

Tags: genesis

Without the "Free-Will" **as inferred**, human being would NOT be human being as He purposed able to 
 chose to obey God.

Genesis 2:16-17 (ESV)
"And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, “**You may surely eat of every tree of the garden,** 17 but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die.”

Comment: Anyone interested, check it out my answer : [google] (https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/what-is-the-will-of-a-man-and-what-is-its-role-in-our-walk-with-god/48135#48135)

Answer (score 1):

Freedom of choice is another of the implicit teachings of Scripture.  However, a few passages come close to being explicit.  Let us examine a sample of the Bible data.

- Gen 2:16, 17 – the original choice given to Adam and Eve to choose service to God as suggested in the OP question.
- 1 Cor 10:13 – God is gracious enough to only allow temptations that we can bear.  This is reveals that God recognises the effect that sin has on our will; sin weakens our will but God helps by both strengthening our will and only allowing temptations that we can bear.
- 2 Peter 3:9 – God is patient wanting all people to decide for Him.
- Gal 5:13 – We are given freedom by God but the privilege should not be abused.
- John 7:17 – People can choose to do the will of God and such a choice bring further enlightenment.
- Josh 24:15 – The Israelites were encouraged to choose God.
- Mark 8:34 – Choosing to serve God involves personal sacrifice which is why it is such a serious decision.
- Rev 3:20 – God wants to be with us but we must choose to allow Him into our lives.
- Gal 5:16, 17, John 8:34-36 – Sin enslaves but the Christian life by the Spirit gives freedom.
- Isa 55:6, 7 – Isaiah encourages the people to choose service to God over all else.
- Deut 30:19, 20 – Moses encourages the people to choose between life and death.
- Exe 18 – an entire chapter about the consequences of choice which ends with the plea, “Repent and live!”

Thus, while Biblically implicit, the concept of the freedom to choose to serve God or otherwise is woven into the very fabric of scripture.

In addition to the above, there is a more fundamental reason why freedom of choice is essential to the plan of salvation.  Observe the following:

- John 13:34, “A new command I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so you must love one another.”
- John 15:12, “My command is this: Love each other as I have loved you.”
- 1 John 4:7, 8, 11, 16,   “Dear friends, let us love one another, for love comes from God. Everyone who loves has been born of God and knows God.  Whoever does not love does not know God, because God is love …  Dear friends, since God so loved us, we also ought to love one another … No one has ever seen God; but if we love one another, God lives in us and his love is made complete in us … And so we know and rely on the love God has for us. God is love. Whoever lives in love lives in God, and God in them … We love because he first loved us.”

It is immediately apparent that love is the very essence of God and our relationship with Him and each other.  Now, here is the point; love cannot be forced else it is not love.  A programmed machine can recite loving sentiments but does not love.  Thus, love can only be love when there is a free choice to love.

Therefore, for love to exist there must be freedom of choice.  Stated the other way, if God were to force us to love and obey Him, we would not love God at all and God would be saving machines.

Now, there are two more complex matters that should be stated.

**1.  Sinful Human Nature**

That we are all sinners is obvious and stated numerous times in Scripture, eg Rom 3:10-18, etc.  This sinful human nature interferes with and reduces our capacity to make truly free choices.  Rom 7 is an extended discussion of this effect.  Organisations like AA are acutely aware of this as well.  However, Jesus said that He came to set us free, Heb 12:1, Gal 3:22, Ps 118:5, Acts 13:38, 39, 2 Tim 1:7, 2:26, etc.

**2.  Free to Believe**

There is a branch of Christianity that suggests that God selected who was to be saved and who was not and people in either group could not do anything about either being saved or unsaved.

In his 1537 Instruction in Faith, John Calvin says (Paul T Fuhrmann tr., 1949, p. 36):

> “For, the seed of the word of God takes root and brings forth fruit
>   only in those whom the Lord, by his eternal election, has predestined
>   to be children and heirs of the heavenly kingdom.  To all the others
>   (who by the same counsel of God are rejected before the foundation of
>   the world) the clear and evident preaching of truth can be nothing but
>   an odour of death unto death.”

This is not the place to debate this extended and huge subject.  All I will suggest here the Bible contains too many examples of people who were saved and subsequently lost for this assertion to be true (see Eze 18 for one such), 2 Peter 1:10, 2:21, 3:17, etc.

**CONCLUSION**

In summary, I believe that Bible teaches us that we have freedom of choice, albeit, limited by our sinful human natures but strengthened by the promptings of the Holy Spirit.

Comment: It is a half millennium old theological problem, and is  a mountain need to be moved. For the dogmas of "group" in  #2,  to be Biblically true, many of  other "Scripture" verses have to be "broken."

Comment: I think it is a case of "Sola Scriptura"fallacy.

Comment: @Sam the irony is they don’t actually start with Scripture to build on Augustine’s gnostic extraBiblical model

Comment: @Nishi Sine Deo, that is why theology should begin with the Scripture, stay with Scripture, and end in the Scripture, and the agent of  "elenctics of the end results of the theologies is the Scripture and the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

Free-will is a convincing but false notion that is easy to use to control a group.  The bible does not explicitly describe free will as a feature we have nor is it universally a part of all mainstream theologies.

The original "choice" in Eden was no such thing.  The man and woman lacked knowledge of good and bad and thus were not moral agents and had no basis upon which to make a decision one way or the other.  It is in Genesis 3:22 that God acknowledges what the serpent told them was true.  They "became knowing good and bad."

One cannot make a freely willed choice under any definition of the term without knowledge of the value metrics on the outcome.  They did not know it was good to follow God's command.  They did not know it was bad to die.  They were not free moral agents in any sense of the term.

Free will is also rejected by a modern deterministic scientific model of the cosmos and was rejected by Hindus and Buddhists a long while before Jesus was on the scene.  This is not something you need modern technology to discern.  I believe that the ancients also realized that we do not have free will, but that it is our condition to believe that we and others do, and it is from that delusion that all suffering comes from.

Hence the calls to obedience to God throughout scriptures point not to a choice, but to a fact about our nature that we are deluded about.

Edit:
I don't think that God or the Serpent lied in Eden.  I think that the woman lied when she said that the serpent tricked her. Everything that the serpent said was true as was everything that God said.  The text is very careful to be ambiguous about what it means to die.

Being a father myself and seeing children grow up, I think this is entirely natural.  Children come to discover this bizarre fact that the thoughts in their head are not accessible to their parents.  Everything the serpents said was true.  The woman was like a kid that broke a lamp and then blamed the dog.

To support this read, I'll post a quote by Barbara Brown Taylor, one of America's most beloved and influential preachers (an Episcopal priest) from an essay she has [in "Birthing the Sermon,"](https://books.google.com/books?id=wjYH9dqFARYC&lpg=PP6&vq=barbara%20brown%20taylor&pg=PA157#v=snippet&q=god%20lied&f=false) a book on feminine perspectives on preaching:

> ...I just read the Adam and Eve passage again and realized, for the first time, that the snake told the truth and God lied.  Well, that is very interesting, and also a little disturbing. ...

This is from a devout voice in a mainline denomination.  These are not esoteric thoughts held by atheists looking to tear apart the text, but by honest reads of the scripture looking to discover the way of the Lord.

Comment: For what you wrote to be true God has to be a deceiver.

Comment: I think you think that that is *bad* thing that has value (good or bad) and that is derived from a concept of an "other" agent...  Which, you know, is the kind of thinking that keeps us from paradise.  That would be a perspective trapped by sin... Which of course is merely our condition, neither good nor bad.  But also, I don't agree with you about God being a deceiver in this context.  I don't think that's true.  I don't think that God OR the serpent lied.  I think that the woman lied when she said that the serpent tricked her.

Comment: 1Tim2:14 and Gen3:13 show that the serpent was a deceiver and the woman was deceived. This is the consequence of the world view you hold, it is forced to reinterpret the Scriptures. If God doesn’t give man free choice (limited though it might be) but claims man has a choice then by necessity God has to be a deceiver too. But given God is not then man prior and after the Garden has free choice apparent from God’s foreknowledge.

Comment: Genesis 3:13 is a record of what the woman said, not a statement from God about the truth of the serpent.  1 Timothy is [typically thought to be written between 130-155](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Epistle_to_Timothy#Date) and is, in any case, not accurate to a reading of the Torah, but to first century midrash like the [_apocalypse of moses_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Adam_and_Eve).  What the serpent said came true.  But that's another topic.  I suggest asking that question (did the serpent lie?), or maybe I will.

Comment: “The Lord God said to the serpent, “ **Because you have done this**, cursed are you above all livestock and above all beasts of the field; on your belly you shall go, and dust you shall eat all the days of your life.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭3:14‬ ‭God doesn’t deny but affirms the woman’s statement and pronounces judgment on her testimony. Thank you for making it clear what view you hold. “But the serpent said to the woman, “You will not surely die.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭3:4‬ ‭Did she not die? She needed covering because now her nakedness was exposed. Spiritually she was cut off and physically she died. All lies

Comment: That's not the only way to read that text, @NihilSineDeo.  She died because God ejected her from Eden denying access to the tree of life.  Not because she ate of the tree of the knowledge of good and bad (or at least not directly).  That much is clear.  And they are ejected not because they ate, but because if they don't, they might take from the tree of life, and this is somehow undesirable to God.  God is choosing to kick them out, if you want to talk about free will.   Read Genesis 3:22-23.  There is a big fat **therefore** in there that links the reason for their expulsion and death.

Comment: God's claim is ambiguous.  He says "in the day you eat of it, you will die" (Gen 2:17), and then the serpent says nope.  You can take that as a euphamism (in the day = when, eventually), but the term is always immediately causal throughout the rest of the text.  Furthermore, in Gen 3:17, Adam's punishment says "in toil you shall eat of it **all the days** of your life;"  So here is a clear contradiction.  Here, adam has many days of life left (even as God perceives days).  But Adam's death was supposed to be caused by eating the fruit... That's all sorts of ambiguous.

Comment: @Gus Lott  if you do not take the Scripture as written you are walking into  a "twilight zone."  Scripture cannot be broken, and should not be broken.

Comment: @Sam, I'm sorry you feel that way.  I am aware of that perspective.  It's not the only one, and your conclusion is one among many, and clearly not the one I make.  Wisdom was the first creation of God along his path (Proverbs 8:22), Wisdom delights in the human race.  Jesus calls us to be wise as serpents in Matthew 10 and uses the same word for wisdom in the septuagint.  Which, itself, has flat out contradictions which were argued over in 1st century scripture.  You can choose to go with the "orthodoxy of man".. I will open my heart and mind to God's wisdom.

Comment: The paragraphs 1,2 & 3, and 5, plus "serpent didn't lie" are very problematic which could mean more serious attempt to the Canon of Scripture.  If you take whole  words of Serpent with its motive, Serpent lied. Truth with a little untruth is NOT Truth anymore. The Free will is not explicit in Scripture so is the Trinity. And definition and the scope of of the free will  clearly drawn in God ' words and commandments: His permission and prohibition, God's mandates, i.e. "subdue.., & prosper & fill the .., and God have Adam to name all the animals. "Free will" is  confined  one, not open.

Comment: The "knowledge of good and evil"  is a "code word" for the "independent being" and equal status with God in deciding what is right and  what is not, just as the serpent, the devil said.  The  meaning of "surely die" is NOT ambiguous, may be "is" in modern "correctness" sense. But it is clearly shown in the series of God's actions, the serious consequences God has to 'give His only begotten Son" to restore.